# "zsh : illegal hardware instruction" m2 macair when Im import imageatm

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, miniconda

Im studying Deeplearning now. In my code, there are 'from imageatm.components import DataPrep', 'from imageatm.components import Training', 'from imageatm.components import Evaluation'. I'm using Miniconda3 environment and python version is 3.6. I already installed imageatm. I knew that imageatm include tensorflow, scipy but just wondering, I installed tensorflow and scipy too. All of that codes are in do.py and when I run 'python3.6 do.py' there are error message : zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3.6 do.py

What's wrong in my code?

I'm not sure but I think it's my hardware problem. I'm using M2 MacBook Air.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code, you just installed a x86_64 version of python or a library that python uses, while you should use ARM versions of all libraries.

Comment: Is python 3.6 support ARM?? I should use 3.6 version...

Comment: *Why* do you want to use Python 3.6? That version has been unmaintained *for years* and should *not* be used.

Comment: I'm just college student.. Professor limited to 3.6. Then which version can I use?

Comment: Talk to your professor then and explain that you can't run such an old version of Python on your computer, since it is unsupported.

Comment: You can run it of course, Python can always be built from source for ARM. I used Python 2.x in ARM platforms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.